# Treat multiple IEnumerable objects as a single IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, join

My question seems to be something easy, but I can't figure it out.

Let's say I have a "root" IEnumerable of objects. Each object has IEnumerable of strings. How can I obtain a single IEnumerable of those strings?

A possible solution is to do:

```
public IEnumerable<string> DoExample()
{
    foreach (var c in rootSetOfObjects)
    {
        foreach (var n in c.childSetOfStrings)
        {
            yield return n;
        }
    }
}
```

But maybe there is a magic solution with Linq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rootSetOfObjects.SelectMany(o => o.childSetOfStrings)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is SelectMany in Linq that should work for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758.aspx#SelectManyCompoundfrom1

it definitely works on your collection and compound collections